# JSON Object Manipulation in java script

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have *JSON* object data in *jsp* file and i have passed this data to *javascript* function through the hyperlink *onclick* method. i am writing the alert box in *javascript* function so it is displayed well but problem is i want to extract the urls in the *JSON* object and convert into an array..

the actual data in *javascript* function is below like that...

```
[Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-1.jpg', description='Exterior', alt='null', sortOrder=1, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-9.jpg', description='Exterior', alt='null', sortOrder=1, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-11.jpg', description='Lobby', alt='null', sortOrder=4, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-5.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-6.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-7.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-8.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-10.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-3.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-2.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-4.jpg', description='Guest Room', alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}]
```

the above text contains the `List` of `Image` Objects contains urls and alt and description and etc...

i need solution in `javascript` to iterate the urls in java script and convert into an array..

please can u suggest the answer for me....

Thanks
Ram Prasad G
08527960397

Comment: That's no JSON, sir. Looks like an Eclipse or Netbeans generated toString() method output.

Comment: If all are image objects, then why cant you fetch the required value, using "url" as the key while iterating the list?

Comment: Looks like you would need to turn all the equals to colons and add a colon between each `Image` and `{`, if you really, really wanted to turn it into an object in javascript only (imagining a regex replace). But then god help you if you ended up with an equals sign in one of your urls or descriptions or something.

Answer (score 1):

I would use JQuery for this purpose. You can go for: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
and while iterating the loop of Images you can do whatever you like with them (including creating an array of them)

**EDIT**

Moreover, as the most people suggested, you're not providing `JSON` format in your quesion.
As I asume, you have data generated by `jsp` (`java`), you could go first for `POJO` to `JSON` on the sever side, that would be on the client side read/parsed by `javascript`.

For the server side to generate JSON for you, I'd use: Jackson. See example on: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 1):

*That's not a valid JSON string.* You will need to roll out your own parsing method to parse content off it correctly.

You should however be able to convert it to valid JSON by doing the following prior to calling a `JSON.parse(..)` on the resultant string.

1. Replace `"Image{"` with `"{"`
2. Replace all `"="` characters with `":"`

Comment: Or he could do `{ Image : {`.